# Avoiding loops in Solidity for a simple situation

Tags: solidity, gas-limit, optimization

Suppose I have a pool that contains some coin say ETH. Imagine there are 100 users that benefit from this pool and I want to keep track of how much ETH in that pool is allocated to each user. When new rewards are sent to that pool (via a transaction) I want the allocation for each user to be updated.

Now when this transaction happens, to update allocations, I could keep track of the allocation of each user (via some mapping) and simply loop through all users and update the new allocation. This would be very gas inefficiant

I am looking for some suggestions that would make this work
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Looping through all users is not just very gas inefficient, it may become impossible once your contract has a lot of users and the looping consumes more gas than the [block gas limit](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50283/why-is-there-block-gas-limit).

I would recommend checking out [ERC-4626](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4626), a standard for a tokenized vaults.

Each depositor receives an amount of ERC-20 *shares* once they deposit the vault's *asset* tokens. The contract computes the amount of *assets* reedemable for the user's *shares* via a [constant computation](https://github.com/transmissions11/solmate/blob/main/src/mixins/ERC4626.sol#L133).

There exist ERC-4626 implementations from [solmate](https://github.com/transmissions11/solmate/blob/main/src/mixins/ERC4626.sol) or [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC4626.sol).
For more info, also see [erc4626.info](https://erc4626.info/).

Note that ERC-4626 does not support native tokens, eg ETH. However, you could just use the WETH token instead of ETH.